# Binded Grid´s Width - but didn't refresh

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, grid, width

I binded a Grid´s Width in WPF:

```
<Grid Width="{Binding MDIWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=dx:DXWindow}}" Name="GridControl">  
...
</Grid>
```

The property is changed, but the Grid didn't refresh it´s size, if the property is changed. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I can only suggest that your `Binding` is *not* working because you *can* set the `Grid.Width` property using a `Binding`. If you are using the `RelativeSource Binding` to access the code behind of the `UserControl` where this `Grid` is, then try this as a test... in the constructor:

```
public DXWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this; 
    MDIWidth = 100.0;
}
```

Then in the view:

```
<Grid Width="{Binding MDIWidth}" Name="GridControl" />
```

If this works, then your original `Binding` has an error.

UPDATE >>>

If you are using the code behind of a `UserControl` to declare your property, then you will need to declare a `DependencyProperty`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty WidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Width", typeof(double), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(250.0));

public double Width
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(WidthProperty); }
    set { SetValue(WidthProperty, value); }
}
```

Apart from you possibly not using a `DependencyProperty`, I don't know why else your code doesn't work... you certainly can update the `Width` of a `Grid` at any time using a `Binding`.

Comment: I think you're right (except you made a typo), you can NOT set the Grid.Width property using a binding because it is not a dependency property.

Comment: I didn't make any mistake... I even tested it... maybe *you* should have tried it before commenting?

Comment: typo in your comment, not in your code. "you can set" -> "you can NOT set".

Comment: Anyways I was wrong, Width is a dependency property and you can bind to it.

Comment: Hello, the binding was not my problem. My Binding in the first post works for me. Its binded with a property value. I've the problem, If the value of the property is changed during runtime, the grid didn't refresh / resize.